# Phonegap build plugins are not being included

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-pushplugin

I've tried many different combinations of files and code to get these phonegap build plugins to function, but so far nothing has worked.

This is the beginning of the index.html I think should work (all but the first script include are not phonegap plugins or directly related to phonegap):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="pushNotif.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="tAuth.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="printR.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="clearCache.js"></script>
```

This is the config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" id="com.example.example" version="0.0.1">
    <name>Example</name>
    <icon src="icon.png" />
    <description>
        Example app.
    </description>
    <author email="support@example.com" href="https://example.com">
        Example
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.5.0" />
    <feature name="Geolocation">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLocation" />
    </feature>
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" version="0.5.2" />
    <gap:plugin name="com.oauthio.plugins.oauthio" version="0.2.4" />
    <gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.pushplugin" version="2.4.0" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs" version="0.2.10" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation" version="0.3.10" />
</widget>
```

Testing to see whether the objects `OAuth` (for [oauth.io](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/962)) or `window.plugins.pushNotification` (for [PushPlugin](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/1199)) are defined or not, I am always getting that they are undefined.

In the folder I have everything together, like:

1. (Essential  Files)

   - config.xml
   - icon.png
   - index.html
2. (App-specific files)

   - printR.js
   - pushNotif.js
   - tAuth.js

(Everything is in one folder, I just separated them in the list.)

So it's pretty simple and straightforward, just as I thought the instructions entailed. However, it's not working, unfortunately.

I tried having the phonegap.js file included, including cordova.js instead, having the file cordova.js, and including the js for the plugins, but I don't think it works that way, so the way I presented is what I think is supposed to be how it's supposed to be set up.

---

This is the script I'm using to handle and check for the phonegap plugin pushplugin:

```
if(typeof window.plugins != "undefined" &&
    typeof window.plugins.pushNotification != "undefined"){
    alert("phonegap pushplugin plugin IS included");//this worked
    handlePushNotif();
} else {
    alert("phonegap pushplugin plugin not included");
}

function handlePushNotif(){
    //https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin/tree/93067b9303252d5ed7394819bf220db56d99d22c

    var pushNotification;
    pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;

    //register
    //Get your senderID by signing into to your google dashboard. The //senderID is found at Overview->Dashboard->Project Number.
    if ( device.platform == 'android' || device.platform == 'Android' )
    {
        pushNotification.register(
            successHandler,
            errorHandler, {
                "senderID":"888264849750",
                "ecb":"onNotificationGCM"
            });
    }
    else
    {
        pushNotification.register(
            tokenHandler,
            errorHandler, {
                "badge":"true",
                "sound":"true",
                "alert":"true",
                "ecb":"onNotificationAPN"
            });
    }
    // result contains any message sent from the plugin call
    function successHandler (result) {
        alert('result = ' + result);
    }

    // result contains any error description text returned from the plugin call
    function errorHandler (error) {
        alert('error = ' + error);
    }

    //tokenHandler (iOS ony) - called when the device has registeredwith a unique device token.
    function tokenHandler (result) {
        // Your iOS push server needs to know the token before it can push to this device
        // here is where you might want to send it the token for later use.
        alert('device token = ' + result);
    }
}
```

If I include the `PushNotification.js` script,  I see that `window.plugins.pushNotification` is not `undefined`. However, with phonegap build, I think it may be designed to include it automatically. If I don't include it manually (copying the file `PushNotification.js` from the git repository to the project files and including it specifically), I get that that object is not defined. However, in the phonegap build dashboard, it shows me that the plugin is indeed included.

Answer (score 1):

Your config.xml is invalid. These lines are bad:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
```

Comment: I apologize, that was an error in my question. The question looked like I had forgotten to put those lines at the top of the `index.html` code, so I copied and haphazardly pasted them in the `config.xml` code. In reality, I had just not left enough space preceding, so those lines didn't show up. The question is fixed now.

Comment: In your project, when you click the Plugins tab, is anything listed?

Comment: All of the plugins are listed properly. And I found out some of them are being included. There's just one in particular, `com.oauthio.plugins.oauthio` that doesn't function properly. Not sure what to do with the question as it's technically now probably a different question -- one concerning a specific plugin.

Comment: Actually, the original question still applies. The push notifications plugin `PushPlugin` is not acting in any way as I would expect. The script I'm using is based off of the documentation script. I have added it to the question. I checked for the `device` object, and that is `undefined`. I have to include `PushNotification.js` for the object `window.plugins.pushnotification` to not be undefined, although I thought that perhaps phonegap build injected the script into the page as a part of the plugin procedure.

Comment: @Ajoy I never did. I'm using cordova locally now.